# HTTP server for Windows Mobile 6

Tags: ajax, windows-mobile-6, httpserver

I have a mobile web app running as client-side JavaScript using Opera Mobile 10 on Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional (on a Motorola MC9500). (I've tried IE Mobile 6, but it doesn't support the canvas element nor enough JavaScript to be useful for my purposes.) I need this app to exchange messages with a native app on the same device. Because JavaScript is sand-boxed and I don't have access to ActiveX, it seems that one way to do this is to send/receive messages via AJAX through an intermediate server on the same device. Does anyone have a recommendation for an HTTP server that will run on Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional? This server should be able to cache the messages with persistent storage, e.g., SQLite.

I'm currently looking at [PocketHPH](http://mobileleap.net/hph/), a PHP server. I have also found [Padarn](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn.aspx), an ASP.NET web server. I welcome any suggestions on small web servers that are better suited to this task.

Thanks.

Here's some clarification of my original question. The original web app is running on iPhone using Safari. It's a pretty complicated JavaScript app which I didn't write. So I'm trying to move it to Windows Mobile without having to rewrite the thing as a native app. The reason I'm moving it is because we're partnering with another company that has an existing native app that must run on an MC9500 which runs Windows Mobile 6.5 Pro. So I don't have any control or access to the code of the native app. However, our web app must exchange messages with the other company's app. Hence, many of the constraints, e.g., I can't use IWebBrowser2 from the native app. The other company's developer could try, but it doesn't look like he's going to go for that because there are much smaller things that he won't do.  My understanding is that I can only use ActiveX from IE Mobile, not from Opera Mobile. However, there are several JavaScript features that IE Mobile 6 doesn't support. So I might be able rewrite the entire JavaScript app to make IE happy (I had already done quite a bit of rewriting before switching to Opera Mobile which has a much better JavaScript engine), but it would probably be easier to just rewrite it as a native app. It might be possible to engineer out the canvas element, but again if I'm going to do that, I might as well bite the bullet and rewrite the whole thing as a native app. So much for trying the "easy" route of porting to another web browser.

Comment: What an unusual question! What unusual constraints?! Ordinarily I would suggest go ActiveX but you rule that out, but, _why_? I feel that it would be a lot less pain to implement your own ActiveX components compared to working with a 3rd party HTTP Server. Can you give some insight on the usage of the canvas element and whether this can be engineered out - i.e. if it's non canvas, you could consider your native app housing the IWebBrowser2 control.

Comment: I think some version of apache was released for free and some version of ASP exists. I don't recall there being a PHP server and the SQL I have seen doesn't include a server...

Comment: Just for documentation: When I used PocketHPH (a long time ago) I hit one major limitation: It couldn't process array form fields, so you couldn't generate a list of items, each of which had the same fields ("first_name[]", "last_name[]", ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think PocketHPH is giving me what I need. It is a compact PHP server that runs on Windows CE devices.  It includes SQLite3.  It is working on my Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional device: a Motorola MC9500.

You can download it here: http://mobileleap.net/hph/

However, it looks like it hasn't been updated since 2007.  So it might be a risky thing to rely on.

I have been able to send/receive AJAX requests/responses from a web-based Javascript app running in Opera Mobile using Cross-Domain Messaging.  I wrote PHP for the server that stores/retrieves the messages to/from the SQLite3 database.

One problem I'm having though: the AJAX cannot connect to the server when the device is offline, even though it is entirely a local connection. For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307745/cannot-connect-to-127-0-0-1-when-offline-using-windows-mobile-6-5-professional-e

Comment: any update you got for your problem? I am doing well with Android, but I need to run the same on Windows Phone and iOS too. Do you get any update from this mobile web server?

Comment: We did not use PocketHPH.  Instead we hired someone to write a custom server.  But we still were not able to connect to a local port when offline.

Comment: thanks for sharing. Hope it solves soon and you may share the code generously!